# Writing a new column in all excel files (and all sheets in an excel file) in a folder using R

Tags: r, excel

So, I have many excel files in a folder, and each file has multiple sheets. If the name of the excel file is 'xyz', I want each sheet of each excel file to contain a 'new_column' such that each row of the new column will contain the excel file name (in this example, 'xyz').

Is there any direct way to do that? I would prefer to directly alter the files in the folder without creating new dataframes within rstudio.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double `lapply` -

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

#Get a vector of xlsx filenames
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  #Read the sheet names
  sheetname <- excel_sheets(x)
  #For each sheet read the data and create list of dataframe
  lapply(sheetname, function(y) {
    cbind(read_xlsx(x, y), filename = x)
  }) -> res
  #Assign names to the list
  names(res) <- sheetname
  #Write the data back
  write_xlsx(res, x)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. 
But I think the filenames vector is making some problems. The first sample excel file name in my directory is called 'excel 1', and I am getting the following error.

 `Error: Evaluation error: zip file './~$excel 1.xlsx' cannot be opened.`

The filename vector is like this (contains only 2 names):
`[1] "./~$excel 1.xlsx" "./~$excel 2.xlsx" "./excel 1.xlsx"   "./excel 2.xlsx" `

Comment: Those are temporary files created in your system. Try using `filenames <- list.files(pattern = "[^~]\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: I get the following error. 

`Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
In addition: Warning message:
In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  :`